# WPF Grid event when leave from grid + mouse click anywhere in out of grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid in WPF View.xaml. This grid has a few control(textbox, DatePicker etc.). I need an event method that,will be when mouse leave from grid +  click anywhere at out of grid.

Hopefully I can express.. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.